# Global minimum when noisy estimates of function available

Tags: optimization, machine-learning

I am interested in knowing about algorithms for finding global minimum when noisy estimates of the function are available.

Comment: possible dup: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/39546/755.  What research have you done?  What methods have you considered?  Also take a look at http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/13343/755.

Comment: @D.W.: I am aware of annealing kind of methods, but that gives convergence in probability rather than a.s. convergence.

Comment: That information ought to be in the question.  Also, it suggests you have a requirement that is not stated (e.g., a.s. convergence).  Second: the comment puzzles me.  I had the impression that things like simulated annealing are heuristics, with almost no meaningful guarantees.  Is this incorrect?  Also, I'm puzzled by reliance on asymptotic notions of convergence: in practice we usually care more about whether it will give a good answer within our lifetime.  Could you expand the question to elaborate more on the perspective you are approaching this from and how you will evaluate answers?